# How to execute zend framework album module in browser

Tags: zend-framework2

I created project **zf2-tutorial** in local-host (**d:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial**) as said in zend documentation and i created album module in modules and how will i test this module in browser.

When i execute this in browser like [http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/album] it is giving **error:** "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album"

Is there any setting in .htaccess file.

Comment: have you set up the virtual host correctly?

Comment: yes like blelow  

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory D:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: can you post your routing config?

Comment: <?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
          'Album',                  // <-- Add this line

    ),

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),

Comment: <?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),
 // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',

Comment: how to link up album module in index.php for testing???

Answer (score 0):

... "NetworkError: 500 .." should be a wrong server configurarion. Check your Server Error-Logfile for more details.

Nevertheless your Zend Application also must be configured correctly:

1. Your new module "Album" must be listed within *application.config.php* as a module
2. Your routing configurarion of your "Album" module must have a valid route to your controller and action. Most comfortable routing configuration is a "Segment" route with [/:controller][:action] parameters

Answer (score 0):

Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2.localhost
    DocumentRoot d:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory d:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In host file of your system:

```
127.0.0.1  zf2.localhost localhost
```

Now run:

```
http://zf2.localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

And also we can see this type of error because of you have not `use` your model or tables.

```
use Inventory\Model\ItemOut;
use Inventory\Model\ItemOutTable;
```

Check whether you have `use` correct `Model`'s.